# Imprimir solo 2 decimales

Tags: python

Se que la pregunta es muy básica, pero me he dado cuenta que si escribo así un `print()`

```
print('Valor %.2f' %(pre[0]*100))
```

no tengo problemas en limitar los decimales que se muestran. En cambio, empleando este segundo método no consigo hacer lo mismo.

```
print(f'Valor de {pre[0]*100}')
```

He probado a poner `.2f` después pero lo considera cómo parte del texto y dentro de las llaves me da error. Entonces, ¿Cómo se haría si quiero imprimir de esta forma? ¿Afecta en algo en Python imprimir de una u otra forma? Por que realmente incluso habría una tercera forma que es separando por comas.

```
print('bla bla bla',miFloat,' bla bla bla')
```

Un saludo y muchas gracias

Comment: Con fstrings es: `print(f'Valor de {pre[0]*100:.2f}')` Ver [la documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando utilizas  Formatted string literals (la letra f dentro de print), puedes escoger el formato de la variable de la siguiente manera:

```
  print(f'Valor de {pre[0]*100 :.2f}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución a tu problema, puede ser meter en una variable lo que quieres mostrar.

Yo lo haría así:

```
foo = 'Valor %.2f' %(pre[0]*100)
print(f'Aqui vengo a dejar el {foo} :-D ')
```

Debería funcionarte